# Optimize time the query with two EXISTS subqueries, and sort by created time

Tags: mysql

The query below is very slow, it takes more than 5 minutes to run:

```sql
SELECT
  id
FROM
  `orders`
WHERE
  (`orders`.`platform_id` IN (2))
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      `order_items`
    WHERE
      (`order_items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`)
       AND (`order_items`.`seller_id` = 1)
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      `shipments`
    WHERE
      `shipments`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
      AND (`shipments`.`seller_id` = 1)
  )
ORDER BY
  `orders`.`created_at` ASC
LIMIT
  10;
```

- The total rows of `orders` with platform_id = 2 is: 1M rows

```sql
SELECT count(1)
FROM `orders`
WHERE platform_id` = 2
```

- The total rows of `order_items` with seller_id = 1 is: 5M rows

```sql
SELECT count(1)
FROM `order_items`
WHERE `seller_id` = 1
```

- The total rows of `shipments` with seller_id = 1 is: 3M rows

```sql
SELECT count(1)
FROM `shipments`
WHERE seller_id = 1;
```

When I explain the query I see the main reason for this slow is:

- Innodb IO Read Wait: 4 minutes.
- Innodb Read Bytes: 407.37 KB (per sec), total: 17GB

I need to optimize it, but I tried too many ways to add more composite indexes, but it seems it does not work.

The innodb_buffer_pool_size is now: 4G.

Comment: With 4G buffer pool, I hope you have at least 6GB of RAM.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: For query performance questions, the `EXPLAIN` plan is a minimum, and also table and index definitions

Answer (score 1):

These may help:

```
orders:  INDEX(platform_id, created_at,  id)
order_items:  INDEX(seller_id, order_id)
shipments:    INDEX(seller_id, order_id)
```

Or this may approach it a different way.  (This is not advised for general use, only because so many rows are involved in your example.)

```
SELECT id
    FROM (
        ( SELECT id FROM orders WHERE platform_id = 2 )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT order_id FROM order_items WHERE seller_id = 1 )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT order_id FROM shipments WHERE seller_id = 1 )
         ) AS u
    JOIN orders  USING(id)
    ORDER BY orders.created_at ASC
    LIMIT 10;
```

The indexes listed above are vital to performance here, too.

Comment: Thank you, I will try then let you know.

Comment: Sorry, I'm late for update, the answer did not fit my question, we need exist but this union, the result is larger then my expectation.

Comment: @vietean - Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for your query with my INDEXes.  (I see that millions of rows for each subquery, my SELECT is unlikely to be fast.)